# Error on ndk-build clean

Tags: android-ndk

I am getting the following error on ndk-build clean

```
mo@mo-Toshiba ~/Workspace/AndroidApp/jni/android_programming_driver $ ndk-build clean
Clean: driveradapter [armeabi]
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
make: *** [clean-driveradapter-armeabi] Error 2
```

Where is the NDK seeing this syntax erro?

Comment: Same problem here on Ubuntu and OSX. Any solution ?

Comment: I never figured it out. I just manually clean by deleted the generated lib/ and objs/ files.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is a [bug in ndk r8e](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2013/03/correcting-a-bug-in-the-latest-google-ndk-r8e.html).

How to fix it:

Edit the file `$(ndk_dir)build/core/build-binary.mk`. Change the line

```
$(cleantarget): PRIVATE_CLEAN_FILES := ($(my)OBJS)
```

to

```
$(cleantarget): PRIVATE_CLEAN_FILES := $($(my)OBJS)
```

For me, that was on line #49.