# Android Eclipse NDK make error 5 - any suggestions to remedy this error?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, makefile

A user is trying to build my project using r8e of the NDK,  and is getting make: error 5.

http://code.google.com/p/frozenbubbleandroid/issues/detail?id=17

I do not see this issue when I build, and have posted multiple suggestions, but nothing is working, including using a previous version of the NDK, making sure the path doesn't have spaces, etc.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The user reported that going to a prior version of the NDK did not work - but I have not tried r8e and use r8d with no issues.  I think r8e is the issue, because other similar problems are being reported with r8e:

[Error on ndk-build clean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15982658/error-on-ndk-build-clean)

This is the full problem:

Reported by trungkientn, Jul 14 (3 days ago)
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/modplug-1.0] Error 5  frozenbubble            C/C++ Problem